# Sqlite with OCaml

Tags: database, sqlite, ocaml

I'm sorry for my bad english if somethig is not clear please ask me and I will explain.
My goal is make back end in OCaml for start to "play seriusly" with this language, I chose to do beck end project because I wanna make front end too in React for improve my skill with React too (I use OCaml for passion, and Ract for job I'm web developer)

I chose sqlite (with this lib: http://mmottl.github.io/sqlite3-ocaml/api/Sqlite3.html) as db for avoid db configuration

I have idea to make little wrapper for db calls(so if I chose to change db type I just need to change it), and make a function like this:

```
val exec_query : query -> 'a List Deferred.t = <fun>
```

but in lib I see this signature for exec function:

```
val exec : db -> ?cb:(row -> headers -> unit) -> string -> Rc.t = <fun>
```

The result is passed row by row to callback, but for my purpose I think I need to have some kind of object (list, array, etc.), but I have no idea how to make it from this function.

Can someone suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Hi @SHI1485. Your question is good and well formulated, no reason to be modest about your English skills or the relevance of this question. The intro (your motivation for the question) is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want `val exec_query : query -> row List Deferred.t`.  Since `Sqlite3` does not know about `Async`, you want to execute the call returning the list of rows in a separate system thread.  The function [`In_thread.run : (unit -> 'a) -> 'a Deferred.t`](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html#working-with-system-threads) (optional args removed from signature) is the function to use for that.  Thus you want to write (untested):

```
let exec_query db query =
  let rows_of_query () =
    let rows = ref [] in
    let rc = Sqlite3.exec_no_headers db query
                ~cb:(fun r -> rows := r :: !rows) in
    (* Note: you want to use result to handle errors *)
    !rows in
  In_thread.run rows_of_query
```

Comment: Or he could just use `rows_of_query` as an example of saving the result while in a callback.